# py.test - how to use a context manager in a funcarg/fixture

Tags: python, pytest, contextmanager

*Closely related:* [In python, is there a good idiom for using context managers in setup/teardown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416208/in-python-is-there-a-good-idiom-for-using-context-managers-in-setup-teardown)

---

I have a context manager that is used in tests to fix the time/timezone. I want to have it in a pytest funcarg (or fixture, we are using `pytest` 2.2.3 but I can translate backwards). I could just do this:

```py
def pytest_funcarg__fixedTimezone(request):
    # fix timezone to match Qld, no DST to worry about and matches all
    # Eastern states in winter.
    fixedTime = offsetTime.DisplacedRealTime(tz=' Australia/Brisbane')

    def setup():
        fixedTime.__enter__()
        return fixedTime

    def teardown(fixedTime):
        # this seems rather odd?
        fixedTime.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

... but it's a bit icky. In the related Q [jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108205/jsbueno) points out: *The problem is that your code has no provision to call the object's `__exit__` method properly if an exception occurs.*

[His answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529165/54056) uses a metaclass approach. But this is not that useful for pytest where often tests are just functions, not classes. So what would be the pytest-y way to solve this? Something involving [runtest hooks](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#generic-runtest-hooks)?

Answer (score 23):

Since 2.4, `py.test` has `yield` style fixture support. We could use a `with` context inside it directly.

```
@pytest.yield_fixture
def passwd():
    with open("/etc/passwd") as f:
        yield f.readlines()
```

Since 3.0, `py.test` deprecated the `@pytest.yield_fixture` usage. We could use `@pytest.fixture` as a context manager directly.

```
@pytest.fixture
def passwd():
    with open("/etc/passwd") as f:
        yield f.readlines()
```

Comment: I think yield style fixtures are deprecated?

Comment: @NeilG Thanks for your comment. I have updated the answer for the pytest 3.0 changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is currently no elegant way of using context managers in fixtures.  However the finalizers will run if the test fails:

```py
import contextlib, pytest

@contextlib.contextmanager
def manager():
    print 'manager enter'
    yield 42
    print 'manager exit'

@pytest.fixture
def fix(request):
    m = manager()
    request.addfinalizer(lambda: m.__exit__(None, None, None))
    return m.__enter__()

def test_foo(fix):
    print fix
    raise Exception('oops')
```

If you run this with `pytest -s` you will see that the `__exit__()` call happens.

Comment: My concern is not that the `__exit__` may not be called, but that it won't be called with the [right values](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). `__exit__` is normally called with values relating to any exception raised in the `with` block (or in this case it would be the test body).