# Using pytest to ensure a file is created and written to

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest and want to test that a function writes some content to a file. So I have `writer.py` which includes:

```
MY_DIR = '/my/path/'

def my_function():
    with open('{}myfile.txt'.format(MY_DIR), 'w+') as file:
        file.write('Hello')
        file.close()
```

I want to test `/my/path/myfile.txt` is created and has the correct content:

```
import writer

class TestFile(object):

    def setup_method(self, tmpdir):
        self.orig_my_dir = writer.MY_DIR
        writer.MY_DIR = tmpdir

    def teardown_method(self):
        writer.MY_DIR = self.orig_my_dir

    def test_my_function(self):
        writer.my_function()

        # Test the file is created and contains 'Hello'
```

But I'm stuck with how to do this. Everything I try, such as something like:

```
        import os
        assert os.path.isfile('{}myfile.txt'.format(writer.MYDIR))
```

Generates errors which lead me to suspect I'm not understanding or using [tmpdir](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html) correctly.

How should I test this? (If the rest of how I'm using pytest is also awful, feel free to tell me that too!)

Comment: There are two questions that address each part of what you are having difficulty I believe. Check them out and see if they provide any insight. Here is one on testing for writing to the file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20531072/writing-a-pytest-function-to-check-outputting-to-a-file-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801662/py-test-how-to-use-a-context-manager-in-a-funcarg-fixture) is one that shows how to use the proper fixture to deal with context managers.

Comment: You should [mock `open()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289894/how-do-i-mock-an-open-used-in-a-with-statement-using-the-mock-framework-in-pyth) so you never actually open a file, but just check if it has been used correctly.

Comment: Can we see more details? How do you generate tmpdir? What are errors?

Comment: @phd `tmpdir` [is a pytest fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html). I don't like how it appears sort of like 'magic', rather than being imported from somewhere... doesn't feel very explicit.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a test to work by altering the function I'm testing so that it accepts a path to write to. This makes it easier to test. So `writer.py` is:

```
MY_DIR = '/my/path/'

def my_function(my_path):
    # This currently assumes the path to the file exists.
    with open(my_path, 'w+') as file:
        file.write('Hello')

my_function(my_path='{}myfile.txt'.format(MY_DIR))
```

And the test:

```
import writer

class TestFile(object):

    def test_my_function(self, tmpdir):

        test_path = tmpdir.join('/a/path/testfile.txt')

        writer.my_function(my_path=test_path)

        assert test_path.read() == 'Hello'
```