# Python unittest similar to pytest scope="session"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

In `pytest` we can define a `session`-scoped fixture, so the following

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def some_fixt():
   ... some setup procedure ...
   yield
   ... some cleanup procedure ...
```

will automagically set things up before testing session begins, and clean things up afterwards.

Is there something similar in `unittest`? The best I can find is `setUpModule`+`tearDownModule`, but that's just per-module, necessitating copy-paste among different testing modules.

---

**EDIT:** This is my current workaround:

**For each and every Test Module:**

```py
from contextlib import ExitStack
...


ModuleResources = ExitStack()

def setUpModule():
    # For funcs/objects that can act as a context_manager
    ModuleResources.enter_context(
        ... something that can act as a context_manager ...
    )
    # For funcs/objects that cannot act as a context manager,
    # but has a "cleanup" method such as "stop" or "close"
    ... invoke setup ...
    ModuleResources.callback(thing.cleanup)


def tearDownModule():
    ModuleResources.close()
```

The problem is, of course, I have to paste all those code for *each and every* test module. So I'm looking for something simpler here.

Comment: I am not familiar with `python-unittest`, however, you likely can just define your own context manager to accomplish this. I googled, "python-unittest context manager" and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416208/in-python-is-there-a-good-idiom-for-using-context-managers-in-setup-teardown

Comment: @Tim the example does setup & teardown per each test case, though. Something I don't want to do. As to the context manager, it's quite easy since I use `contextlib.ExitStack`.

Comment: @Tim I've edited my question to show my current, unsatisfactory implementation.

Comment: I see. Well, if you don't want a per module fixture, then you could do the context manager in whatever calls the main set of tests? Like, make a wrapper for your tests suite?